# My Database Search is too broad and won't discriminate

Tags: c#

so I made a database however it is not searching properly. I want to search for example for an individual employee using their name or id, however when I start the search instead it brings up the entire database. here is my code.

```
namespace FairyTailHRSolution
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlDataAdapter da;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con=new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = LAPTOP-VHSGV41H\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = EmpDB; Integrated Security = True");
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO FRYEMP (EmployeeID, EmployeeName, EmployeePosition, EmployeeSalary) VALUES (@EmployeeID, @EmployeeName, @EmployeePosition, @EmployeeSalary)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeName", textBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeePosition", textBox3.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeSalary", textBox4.Text); 
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void find_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(comboBox1.Text == "EmployeeID")
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LAPTOP-VHSGV41H\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EmpDB;Integrated Security=True");
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT EmployeeID, EmployeeName,EmployeePosition, EmployeeSalary FROM FRYEMP where EmployeeID like '" + "%'", con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
            else if (comboBox1.Text == "EmployeeName")
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LAPTOP-VHSGV41H\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EmpDB;Integrated Security=True");
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT EmployeeID, EmployeeName,EmployeePosition, EmployeeSalary FROM FRYEMP where EmployeeName like '" + "%'", con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you passing parameters in the first place???

Comment: All you are doing is concatenating `%`, there is no other string you are adding. Before you add a string though you should learn how to use parameters, otherwise you will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks. Change your sql to `WHERE EmployeeName like @employeeName` and then add a sql parameter with the value `"%your search word here%"`

Comment: you are just saying fetch records with employes like %

Comment: thanks for your response guys, I edited my post so please check it out and keep in mind I am still a beginner

Comment: Let me rephrase: Do something with the value of `textBox5` which is also passed in to your event as `sender`. Someone spent their time typing in some search text and you (*your code*) are completely ignoring everything they typed.

Comment: change your wild card to be `% + search Criteria + %`

Answer (score -1):

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT EmployeeID, EmployeeName,EmployeePosition, EmployeeSalary FROM FRYEMP where EmployeeName like @employeeName", con);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeName","%" + textBox5.Text + "%");
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Similar application for employeeId.  Also I'd consider using stored procedures for something like this, since stored procedures are pre-compiled and cached and will be more performant for this kind of operation.